# the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, django, angularjs, rest

I am trying to send PUT request to my API written in [Django Restless](https://github.com/toastdriven/restless). I have tried Curl and AngularJS, however, I always get this error:

```
the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

I am using Python 3.4 on OS X. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. This is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/toastdriven/restless/issues/14) on Django Restless. There's also [a fix](https://github.com/toastdriven/restless/pull/17) that is a couple months old and yet to be merged.

Until that is merged and a new version is released, I suggest either using a different Django REST framework, downgrading to Python 2, or commenting on the issues and pull requests above to spur a response from the developer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably I will have to stick with DRF.